# Clickable Navbar title

Tags: iphone, sdk, uinavigationcontroller

How can I make the title of a navbar clickable. Much like in the facebook application. Were when you click it it dismisses the view controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set a `UIButton` as UINavigationItem's `titleView`.. add an action to that button.. for more details read [UINavigationItem class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006933-CH3-SW2)